# how to return the data like a array form remote store extjs

Tags: arrays, extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have grid with filter and on the filter i want to show a list of items. By focusing the filter option I should see a list of items with check boxes and when I click on the check box it should send the params. I achieved this by
loading local data and I want the same by loading remote data how can I achieve it.
    {
        dataIndex: 'adjustmentTypeDescription',
        text: 'Adjustment
Type',
        stateId: 'adjustmentgrid_adjustmentTypeDescription',
        filter: {
            type: 'list',
            labelField: 'name',
            dataIndex: 'adjustmentTypeId',

```
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            fields: [{
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }],
            data: [
                [2, 'AA'],
                [13, 'AFF'],
                [11, 'DDD'],
                [15, 'Dd'],
                [5, 'Fdsdt'],
                [6, 'Ide']
                [10, 'Return/Reject']
            ]
        })}
```

Now I want to load this data from the service.
I tried this way:

```
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            autoLoad: false,
            model: 'ModelName',
                        /*fields: [{
                                name: 'adjustmentTypeId',
                                type: 'int'
                            }, {
                                name: 'description',
                                type: 'string'
                            }],*/
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: 'servicurl',
                            timeout:120000,
                            reader: {
                                type: 'array',
                               // rootProperty: 'data',
                                rootProperty:function(data){
                                    debugger;
                                    return data;
                                    debugger;
                                    //console.log(bb);
                                }
                            }
                        }/*,
                        listeners: {
                            load: function(store, records, successful, 
                      operation, eOpts){
                                debugger;
                                var data = [];
                                for(var i = 0; i< 1; i++){

                   //data.push(records[i].data.description);
                                    var vare = new Array();
                                    vare[0]= records[i].data.description;
                                    data.push(vare);

                                }

                                store.loadData(data);
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        }*/
            })
```

but didn't work how can I achieve this by making a service call and loading the remote data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set `autoLoad`: true
2. Remove the `reader` config object. Since you are using an ArrayStore, this is not needed. And array data is positional so `rootProperty` is not used.
3. Check that you have defined the Model fields correctly.

It should work.

Comment: My mistake actually the store shoudn't be ArrayStore because the data from the server is in json format:

Comment: I changed it to json reader and got it https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28ko